# How can I embed a function call inside another function?

Tags: .net, f#

So I have a function that I've pulled from a tutorial:

```
let sumOfSquares nums = 
    nums
    |> Seq.map sqr
    |> Seq.sum
```

I have decided that I want to test its performance.  In a brute-force approach, I would do something like:

```
let timeFunction nums =
    let sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch()
    sw.Start()
    nums
        |> Seq.map sqr
        |> Seq.sum
    sw.Stop()
    sw.ElapsedMilliseconds
```

However, this struck me as a good example for how F# is supposed to treat functions as first-class citizens.  So I tried to do something like the following, instead:

```
let timeFunction fn x =
    let sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch()
    sw.Start()
    fn x
    sw.Stop()
    sw.ElapsedMilliseconds
```

And then I tried to call it:

```
let sequenceOfNums = [for i in 1..20 -> i]
let print n = System.Console.WriteLine(n.ToString())
print "Time Trial"
print (timeFunction sumOfSquares sequenceOfNums)
```

However, this fails with the following error:

> Type mismatch. Expecting a     'a -> unit     but given a     'a ->
>   int     The type 'unit' does not match the type 'int'

on the line that calls the function.  Do I have some sort of syntactical error here, or have I grossly misunderstood a concept?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the result of `fn` isn't being used it's inferred to be `unit`. You can fix this by piping the result to the `ignore` function. It's signature is `'a -> unit`, so it makes the return type of `fn` generic (which is what you want).

```
let timeFunction fn x =
    let sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch()
    sw.Start()
    fn x |> ignore
    sw.Stop()
    sw.ElapsedMilliseconds
```

Comment: And piping to ignore won't cause it to be optimized away or anything, right?